# Migration of thymeleaf version 2.14 to 3.0 not finding message properties

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, properties-file

Thymeleaf version 2.14 was picking up message.properties file correctly. After migration to 3.0,it is giving error ??hello.MESSAGE_en_US??.
But in javacode by autowiring messsagesource

```
messageSource.getMessage( "hello.MESSAGE",null, Locale.getDefault()) ->Hello App
```

The project structure

```
 src/main/
       -java
          -com.cando
            -controllers
       -resources
         -messages_en.properties
         -spring.properties
       -webapp
         -WEB-INF
           -templates
             -index.html
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
        <head>
            <title>Helllo</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p th:text="#{hello.MESSAGE}">Hello App!</p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

messages_en.properties

```
hello.MESSAGE=Hello App
```

config

```
   @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        resourceBundleMessageSource.setBasename("messages");
        resourceBundleMessageSource.setBasename("spring");
        return resourceBundleMessageSource;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your config file you `setBasename()` to *messages* and then override value to *spring*. I think `ResourceBundleMessageSource` just doesn't see your *messages* file, and you should add it like: `setBasenames("messages","spring")`. Give it a try and tell if it works :)

Comment: tried by using setBasenames("messages","spring")  but issue didn't solve

Answer (score 1):

I think i found solution

While you configure SpringTemplateEngine it's possible to explicitly set messageSource and messageResolver.

For me, this works.

My code in kotlin:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
open class ThymeleafConfig {

   @Autowired
   lateinit var applicationContext: ApplicationContext

   @Autowired
   lateinit var messageSource: MessageSource

   @Autowired
   lateinit var messageResolver: SpringMessageResolver

   @Bean
   open fun viewResolver(): ViewResolver = ThymeleafViewResolver().apply     
   {
       templateEngine = templateEngine()
       characterEncoding = "UTF-8"
   }


   fun templateEngine(): TemplateEngine = SpringTemplateEngine().apply {
       enableSpringELCompiler = true
       setTemplateResolver(templateResolver())
       setMessageSource(messageSource)
       addMessageResolver(messageResolver)
   }

   fun templateResolver(): ITemplateResolver = SpringResourceTemplateResolver().apply {
       prefix = "file:./web/templates/"
       suffix = ".html"
       templateMode = TemplateMode.HTML
       cacheTTLMs = 0
       isCacheable = false
       setApplicationContext(applicationContext)
   }
}

@Component
class MessageResolverImpl: SpringMessageResolver() {    }
```

and messageSource bean:

```
@Bean
open fun messageSource(): MessageSource {
    val source = ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource()
    source.setBasename("classpath:messages")
    source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true)
    source.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8")
    return source
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: thanks it has worked by setting templateEngine.setMessageSource( messageSource );